# How to extrapolate with scipy

Tags: extrapolation

I am trying to predict my uncompleted distribution function tail with scipy.interpolate.interp1d, but ı can not get expected results, ı have tried some parameters of the scipy function but it failed. The below graph may be show my real aim, ı want to see finished graph like yellow line, Do you have any advise?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIlFl.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hi again actually if you open the above img link my desire will be more clear, think about normal curve probabilty distribution but half of the graph is empty , is there any solution to fill empty area like yellow line of the above link

Comment: And the graph dont have to be like normal, skewness can be negative or positive